# cakephp3.x inseritng data in two tables at once

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two tables, `shashis` and `shashi_details`. All I want to do is to insert the data in both the tables at once, so when I'm inserting data, it only goes to the `shashis` table and not in the other table. So please help me out.

this is my ShashisTable.php

```
    class ShashisTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('shashis');
        $this->setDisplayField('name');
        //$this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasOne('ShashiDetails', [
            'foreignKey' => 'shashi_id'
        ]);
    }
```

and this is my ShashiDetails.php

```
     public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('shashi_details');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Shashis', [
            'foreignKey' => 'shashi_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
```

and this is add.ctp of Shashis template

```
    <?= $this->Form->create($shashi) ?>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Shashi') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
            echo $this->Form->input('email');
        ?>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add details') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('shashi_detail.first_name');
            echo $this->Form->input('shashi_detail.last_name');
        ?>
    </fieldset>

    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
```

and this is ShashisController.php

```
 public function add()
    {
        $shashi = $this->Shashis->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) 
        {
            $shashi = $this->Shashis->patchEntity($shashi, $this->request->getData(), [
                'associated' => ['ShashiDetails']
                ]);

            if ($this->Shashis->save($shashi)) 
            {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The shashi has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The shashi could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('shashi'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['shashi']);
    }
```

Comment: Check the validation as well. Try to `debug( $shashi->getErrors());` in the else part of the `$this->Shashis->save($shashi)`.

Comment: @AmanRawat see this video ,i have done this from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTbpvVFYbDU&list=PLG7J_gODl5Ko589KCYUym-0q67-T32CVt&index=4

Comment: The syntax you are using is correct. I am just asking to check if there is any validation error or not? If you can provide the full code of ShashisTable.php

Comment: @AmanRawat no sir,there is no validation error,and how can i show you the full code of model?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should works :

```
if ($this->Shashis->save($shashi)) 
{
    $shashi_details = $this->Shashis->ShashisDetails->newEntity();
    $shashi_details = $this->Shashis->ShashisDetails->patchEntity($shashi_details, $this->request->getData());
    if ($this->Shashis->ShashisDetails->save($shashi_details))
    {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The shashi has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

If it does not, check your POST content and replace also your input('shashi_detail.first_name') and input('shashi_detail.last_name') by input('first_name') and input('last_name').

Comment: if we remove the model name(shashi_detail) then how it will be able to insert the record in shashi_details table?

Comment: and sir, your suggested code is also not working,i have done this coding grom this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTbpvVFYbDU&list=PLG7J_gODl5Ko589KCYUym-0q67-T32CVt&index=4